# implementation inheritance problem in FE design

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I don't know anything about MFC. But I came to know that it has a class `CWnd` which wraps up win32 API calls. And, there are controls - `CListBox` and such that derive from `CWnd`.

Q1: `CWnd` is an interface class. `CListBox` derives from an implementation class. General advice is to avoid this. Is Microsoft wrong or isn't implementation inheritance that bad?

Q2: [This UML](http://www.gliffy.com/publish/2380318/) describes one problem we got. Any ideas on what to do is welcome. One suggestion was to use a macro to "inject" common implementation code. I raised a question on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334041/oop-vs-macro-problem). Bounty expires today.

EDIT: Edited class diagram.

Answer (score 2):

### Q1.

There is no general advice to avoid implementation inheritance. People do that all the time.

On the other hand, MFC is the premier example of Just Bad™ C++ design. That's because it's (1) very old and pre-standard, (2) is a dumbed-down version of a more C++ like library called AFX (as I recall) which turned out to be too "complicated" for programmers at the time.

So, summing up, your Q1 is raising a "false dichotomy": there is no contradiction between both implementation inheritance being OK, Microsoft being wrong, MFC being an example of generally bad design, and whatever quality that `CListBox` has.

### Q2.

The question is essentially, paraphrase, "is it a good idea to generate common code for classes by using code-generation macros?".

The answer to that is no, it's generally not a good idea.

It's totally evil. Although this evil can be the *least evil* in certain cases, such as providing a `clone` implementation, but then we're talking about the macro doing something that C++ does not support, namely general covariant implementation of a member function. However, this is so fine a point that most SO residents fail to understand it (I know because I raised this in one answer to question, and it got heavily downvoted), so I should perhaps not bring it up – suffice it to say that in general, hey, it's evil.

So you know what you should *not* do.

But as to what would be a good alternative, well that depends on the context.

And your context is too vaguely sketched to provide any real good advice on that.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: I feel that the second question is appropriately described in the design diagram. What else would you like to know?

Comment: @nakiya - re Q2 - use a mixin (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin). Implement it either in terms of [multiple][virtual] inheritance, or via CRTP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: @atzz: If you were to state this in an answer, I'd mark it as solution because your suggestion led me to achieving what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

General advice does not mean that it is right for any specific class. Seriously. It might be better to inherit from interfaces most of the time- but that's very, very far from saying "class X should not implementation inherit from class Y for any X and Y". You can't just pick on any example and say that it's bad. You would have to understand the entire source code.

Not just that, but MFC as a library originates from well before Standard C++, and exhibits workarounds for things that aren't in the language, and that sort of thing. It's not really a viable C++ library anymore- for example, their `CArray<T>` implementation uses memcpy to copy objects instead of the copy constructor and is clearly redundant thanks to vector.